# Axapta 3.0 How to change Company permission for user?

Tags: sql-server, sql, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2009

We got an old axapta 3.0 Server to manage of one of our customers.
The problem is our customer needs this old server to access old company data and no one has a plan how to administrate it.
We need to change the permissions for several users that they are able to access other companies within axapata.

We found out that apparently the settings need to be changed within the sql server database, is that true?
We have no plan how to achieve this tasks on this old 2002 dinosaur.

Thank you!

Comment: I don't have access to a 3.0 environment atm, but I can tell you that changing the permissions within the application for users is NOT done in the database, but within the administration module of the application. If you don't mind your users having access to everything, you can give them system administrator permissions. Otherwise, you have to give them permission for the companies you want them to access. Talk to someone from the company that introduced the application to your company, they should be able to help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

To configure what users can do in a company, go to the Administration module and open the Users form. Click on the button that says Permissions. In the right grid, select the company for which you want to change the user's access. Then, select the second tab that is labeled Permissions. In the tree view of the permissions, select the permissions you want to grant to the users and set the access level.